# How is __setitem__() working with 4 arguments?

Tags: python, matrix, operator-overloading

I'm writing a `Matrix` class with the `[]` operator overloaded.

Since my `self.matrix` which holds the matrix is a list of lists, the `__getitem__()` method as per convention takes 2 parameters `self, index`,  returns a list(row) which can further be subscripted.
But what about `__setitem__()`? Isn't it supposed to take only 3 parameters by definition? I have tried it with 4 parameters and it is somehow working fine.
I know a tuple argument can be passed in to access the matrix elements but I would like to know **why** is this working with 4 parameters? Is this undefined behavior?  If I write `m_obj[rindex][cindex] = val`, it works flawlessly!

Also if I just do `m_obj[rindex] = val`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    a[1] = 1
TypeError: __setitem__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'
```

But this indeed is what I want except the positional argument missing was `cindex` not `val`.

On the contrary, if I add an additional parameter to `__getitem__()`, the code doesn't work :

```
 def __getitem__(self, rindex, cindex):
        return self.matrix[rindex][cindex]
```

And I get this error both while getting and setting:

```
>>> a[1][1] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    a[1][1] = 1
TypeError: __getitem__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cindex'
```

Here's the code:

```py
class DimensionError(BaseException):
    pass


class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, rows, cols):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.matrix = [[] for i in range(self.rows)]
        for i in range(self.rows):
            self.matrix.app
            for j in range(self.cols):
                self.matrix[i].append(0)

    def __str__(self):  
        matrep = ''
        for i in self.matrix:
            matrep += str(i) + '\n'
        return matrep

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.matrix[index]

    def __setitem__(self, rindex, cindex, val):
        self.matrix[rindex][cindex] = val

    def __add__(self, secmat):
        if self.rows != secmat.rows or self.cols != secmat.cols:
            raise DimensionError('Incompatible Matrices for Addition')
        newmat = Matrix(self.rows, self.cols)
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                newmat[i][j] = self[i][j] + secmat[i][j]
        return newmat

    def __sub__(self, secmat):
        if self.rows != secmat.rows or self.cols != secmat.cols:
            raise DimensionError('Incompatible Matrices for Subtraction')
        newmat = Matrix(self.rows, self.cols)
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                newmat[i][j] = self[i][j] - secmat[i][j]
        return newmat

    def __matmul__(self, secmat):
        if self.cols != secmat.rows:
            raise DimensionError('Incomatible Matrices for Multiplication. Product is undefined')
        newmat = Matrix(self.rows, secmat.cols)
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(secmat.cols):
                for k in range(secmat.rows):
                    newmat[i][j] += (self[i][k] * self[k][j])
        return newmat

    def __mul__(self, secmat):
            return self.__matmul__(secmat)


#Driver
a = Matrix(2, 2)
b = Matrix(2, 2)
print('Enter elements of first matrix:')
for i in range(a.rows):
    for j in range(a.cols):
        a[i][j] = int(input(f'Enter element [{i}{j}] >>>'))

print('Enter elements of second matrix:')
for i in range(b.rows):
    for j in range(b.cols):
        b[i][j] = int(input(f'Enter element [{i}{j}] >>>'))

print('Matrix a: ')
print(a)
print('Matrix b: ')
print(b)
print('Multiplication is:')
print(a @ b) # or a * b
```

I have tried it in Python 2.7 without f-strings and `@` operator and it works just the same .

Can someone explain what is going on under the hood?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *isn't* working. It isn't being called at all.

When you do `m_obj[rindex][cindex] = val`, Python calls `__getitem__` to get the value of `m_obj[rindex]`. Then it will call the `__setitem__` method of whatever that value is. You can prove this to yourself by putting a print within your method.

Comment: Thank you! So do you recommend rather not defining `__setitem__()` for my class?